# Bokeh MultiSelect

Tags: python, multi-select, bokeh

Can someone share a basic version of a multiselect bokeh plot?

I have an interface that works perfectly in Chrome, but crashes IE on selection.  The console in Chrome and IE are not logging any errors.

It's a very simple case

this is a portion of the update function

```py
def update():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:/....../enps.db')
    connection=engine.connect()
    metadata = MetaData()

    responses = Table('detail_view', metadata,
            Column('business_unit', String),
            Column('location', String),
            Column('job_function', String),              
            Column('opp', String),
            Column('opp_detail', String),
            Column('yes', REAL),
            Column('no', REAL),
            Column('unsure', REAL),
            Column('total', REAL)
         )
    myLocations = [i for i in m_select.value]
    myLocation =  myLocations[0]
    if (myLocation != "All"): #specific location, all bu, all jf
```

And this is the code that initialized the multiselect and calls the on_change property:

```py
    mlocations = [ row[0] for row in pd.read_csv('.../location.txt',   
header=None).values.tolist()]
    m_select = MultiSelect(title="Location", value=mlocations, options=mlocations)
    m_select.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())
    m_select_widgetbox = widgetbox(m_select)
    l=gridplot([[m_select_widgetbox],[header], [plot3], [plot2]])
```

IE crashes.  But then refreshes with the correctly updated plots.  Chrome works just fine.

Thanks

## Update:

I've boiled this down to the simplest code possible just to see if there is some kind of postback error.  I don't understand what could possible be wrong with this code.  Again, it works fine in Chrome.

```py
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Paragraph, MultiSelect
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def update(attrname, old, new):
    myString = ''
    for i in m_select.value:
        myString += '\n' + i
    myText.text = myString

mlocations = [ row[0] for row in pd.read_csv('C:/....../location.txt', header=None).values.tolist()]
m_select = MultiSelect(title="Location", value=mlocations, options=mlocations)
myText = Paragraph(text='Initial Text', width=1200)
m_select.on_change('value', update)
m_select_widgetbox = widgetbox(m_select)
l=gridplot([[m_select_widgetbox],[myText]])
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "wtf"
```

run the bokeh server with IE, change the selection, and you get this...

[IE Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuQqQ.jpg)

Comment: Is this also occurring when you update Bokeh to the newest version? IE is not very standards compliant. MS at this point is also recommending users to stop using IE and switch to their new browser instead which is not much of help to you I know. Can other people or you on a different machine reproduce the issue?

Comment: Bug confirmed with Bokeh 0.12.4 and IE11.0.9600. No Problem with Select-Widget (single). Opened https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6333